# How To Install The Adobe Flash Plugin In Firefox (Snap Package)?

Tags: firefox, flash, snap, plugins

I recently installed the Firefox snap package [(originally announced here)](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/03/firefox-snap-package-available).

Aside from lacking global menu / locally integrated menu support, everything is working flawlessly. However, the snap package doesn't include the Adobe Flash plugin.

The following are the only two extensions that come bundled in the snap:

- OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc.
- Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc.

As this is the first snap app I've installed, I'm not familiar with the directories where extensions are installed, or how to go about installing them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to install the plugin in Firefox, but perhaps I could help you install it on your machine in general?

Comment: I have it installed on my machine, and it works fine in the version of Firefox that is updated in Ubuntu's repos. However, it is not accessible in the snap.

Comment: Oh alright! Sorry, for not being able to help !

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the response!

Comment: My guess, without any proof, is that you can't. A lot of content is available as HTML5 although there are hold-outs still using Flash. Anyway, please keep your question updated with what you find and in case you do find a solution to your question, please post an answer. A lot of people would be interested!

Comment: Will do. I realize that Flash is being deprecated along with other NPAPI plugins, but it still struck me as odd that it wasn't included in the snap package. Especially since Adobe is supporting Flash through 2020. Given this was the first release of the snap package, I was hoping it was more of an oversight or something to be included in a future update, rather than an intentional decision or something for which there is a technical or legal barrier to its inclusion.

Comment: So I found the relevant Firefox snap directory (/snap/firefox/current/) to try and install the Flash extension manually. However, I'm unable to copy "libflashlayer.so" to the directory even with "gksudo naitlus." The directory says it is owned by root, yet I'm unable to access it with superuser permissions. Could this be due to snap confinement, and is there a way around it?

Comment: I keep receiving errors like this, when trying to change the permissions of the directory: "The permissions could not be changed. Sorry, could not change the permissions of “current”: Error setting permissions: Read-only file system." I don't have issues with any other program directories, just the snap directory. The directory /snap/firefox/current/ has the following permissions: "Owner: root = Create and delete files. Group: root = Access files, Others = Access files"

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, Mark Johnson had it correct but he deleted. The way I always install flash is to go here - https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

In the drop downs choose linux & the .tar.gz for for NPAPI. Extract  the download, copy `libflashplayer.so` to `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/plugins` folder, creating that plugins folder as it won't exist.

That's it. One can go to the `about:plugins` URL to see if it is up-to-date. If it complains that it's out-of-date (or a website you visit complains that it's out-of-date), just follow the same procedure to update it

[image: Shockwave Flash appears in the Plugins section]

Comment: This works. I was struggling away with the adobe-flashplugin package before coming across this answer. Just to add that you don't need to copy the /usr files as recommended in the extracted readme.txt file