# Flash plugin not working on Firefox snap and Chromium snap on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I am having problems installing Flash Plugin for Firefox snap and Chromium snap on Ubuntu 19.10.
I did exactly what is written in the Ubuntu Documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html.en in the "Web browser provided as a snap package" section. I also read this Ask Ubuntu question: [How To Install The Adobe Flash Plugin In Firefox (Snap Package)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015359/how-to-install-the-adobe-flash-plugin-in-firefox-snap-package). But whatever I do it just does not work.
I copied the libflashplayer.so file to the ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/plugins folder, but when I go to about:plugins URL there is no Flash plugin listed and also no error.
I have tried closing and opening Firefox, logging out of my account and back in and also rebooting my PC.
Same issue with Chromium.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Carla

Comment: I tested with FF snap and can confirm the problem, unfortunately. I wrote the help.ubuntu.com instruction about this, and it worked at the time. (Flash still works on FF as a .deb package.)

Comment: Hi Gunnar, thanks for the answer. Where do you get the .deb package? It doesn't download from Adobe's site :(.

Comment: I meant FF as .deb (as opposed to snap). `sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: Oh, sorry :( looks like I misunderstood :-P

Comment: Thanks very much for you help,  it worked.